# Cola.js + d3.js force directed network - constraining nodes during/after force solver runs

Tags: svg, d3.js, hierarchy

I'm creating a force-directed heirarchy plot using Cola.js and d3.js.  Nodes are stacked on rows using Y constraints which I have pre-calculated based on the maximum depth of a given node in the heirarchy.

Is there a good way using Cola.js to also constrain nodes to columns in conjunction with the force solver?  I want to center the nodes around Y but also use the force solver's positioning to compute shortest edge distance and thus minimize edge crossing.

The goal is to make the plot dragging less "squishy," so nodes should be constrained to columns after/during the force solver positioning.  The fiddle provided below works pretty well, but with very large networks, the overall inertia of the network is high, so dragging a single node does not move the entire network as fast as I want.

If there is a way to stiffen the force solver, so that dragging a node quickly moves the entire network, that could work instead of using the X offset constraints.  Cola attempts to simplify the node solver by eliminating some of the force options that d3 has, such as charge and gravity, so I can't use these (?) to make dragging the network snappier.

Since Cola takes the constraints as an argument prior to running the solver, setting constraints while preserving optimal node positioning is proving difficult.

... (example code too large to paste)

```
d3cola
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.relationships)
    .constraints(graph.constraints)
    .symmetricDiffLinkLengths(30)
    .start(5,10,20);
```

...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k54ohxor/1/

Cola alignment example: http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/alignment.html

[image: screenshot]

In the above example screenshot, looking at depth level 3 of the heirarchy, you can see that if I pre-constrain the nodes in the order they come in from the database, that would result in poor node positioning and unwanted edge crossing, as the node IDs have the order 7,6,9,8

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to drag a node in the network and have the entire network follow without any springiness?

One thing you could do is to create a single pair of alignment constraints (x and y) that preserve the relative horizontal and vertical separations between nodes that comes out of the initial layout.  That is, use the result of the first call to d3cola.start(5,10,20)  (increase the numbers passed in to control the number of iterations of initial layout) to determine x and y offsets for alignment constraints that you then add.

Another question though, if you just want to drag the whole graph around as if it was a rigid single object, why not just allow dragging of a parent group within the SVG rather than having cola do it?  You mentioned columns though, so maybe you just want to create an x alignment constraint?

Comment: I ended up implementing a zoom function and disabling node dragging entirely. However this presents another problem, occasionally nodes will end up overlapping in large networks (even with avoidOverlaps=true) so now I do need to re-enable node drag to allow users to manually sort that out, along with the pan/zoom.  Trying to use stopPropagation() for that but it's not working yet. For now panning and disabling drag turned out to be the easiest solution... but the saga continues. Thanks for the tip (and cola)